# Integrate Google Streetview map into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tiles, google-street-view, quickmapservices

I'd like to show a the Google Maps layer that has the routes that streetview has taken in my QGIS 2.18.x project.  I'm not looking for the actual street view imagery.  I've seen multiple posts about including the imagery, but I'm interested in tiles. :)  I have QuickMapsServices plugin installed, and was hoping there was an easy way to integrate something.

Here's a screen shot of what I'm looking to duplicate.
[image]

Comment: I don't think it can be done. You could create it yourself but it would be a lot of work. Traversing all the roads and hitting the Google StreetView Metadata API.